# How to make 2 divs on 1 side (up&down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make 2 DIVs in right or left side? How to maintain div position above and below? How to keep close the button of the social network. It needs to support IE8. Please help me.

CSS

```
/* Searchform 
------------------------------------------------*/
.reach{
    margin-right:20px;
    float:right;
}
input#s{
    padding:5px 10px;
    width:190px;
    background:#3a3a3a;
    border:1px solid #555;
    color:#eee;
}

input#searchsubmit{
    padding:4px 10px;
   background: #b30c09;
   border:1px solid #E5110D;
   box-shadow:none;
   color:#fff;
  }

/* Social
------------------------------------------------*/

#social{
float:right;
margin-top:60px;
margin-right:20px;
}
#social li{
text-indent: -3000px;
display:inline;
float:right;
}
#social li a{
display:block;
width:37px;
height:37px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#social li.rss{
background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-BHE0kA2yQDo/UXsAmEaWl3I/AAAAAAAACeI/Ojdu4dH8j3Y/s000/rss-icon.png);
background-position: top;
}
#social li.rss:hover{
background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-BHE0kA2yQDo/UXsAmEaWl3I/AAAAAAAACeI/Ojdu4dH8j3Y/s000/rss-icon.png);
background-position: 0 -37px;
}
#social li.facebook{
background-image: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-hj3G3FJaRWI/UXsAmXImhJI/AAAAAAAACeQ/vqjcAuFkU3s/s000/facebook-icon.png);
background-position: top;
}
#social li.facebook:hover{
background-image: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-hj3G3FJaRWI/UXsAmXImhJI/AAAAAAAACeQ/vqjcAuFkU3s/s000/facebook-icon.png);
background-position: 0 -37px;
}
#social li.twitter{
background-image: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-aK5JgKcwvQE/UXsAmvwR8-I/AAAAAAAACeY/XaMno5_AoIw/s000/twitter-icon.png);
background-position: top;
}
#social li.twitter:hover{
background-image: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-aK5JgKcwvQE/UXsAmvwR8-I/AAAAAAAACeY/XaMno5_AoIw/s000/twitter-icon.png);
background-position: 0 -37px;
```

HTML

```
<div class='reach'>
<form expr:action='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;search/&quot;' id='searchform' method='get'>
    <input class='field' id='s' name='q' placeholder='Ingin mencari sesuatu?' type='text'/>
    <input class='submit' id='searchsubmit' name='submit' type='submit' value='Cari!'/>
</form>
</div>
<div>
<ul id='social'>
<li class='twitter'><a href='http://twitter.com/empayarmasr'>Twitter</a></li>
<li class='rss'><a href='http://busby-btemplates.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default'>RSS</a></li>
<li class='facebook'><a href='http://www.facebook.com/empayarmasr'>Facebook</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

My code at >>> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjsbdLdk/)

Comment: Could you re-phrase your question so it's clearer and more understandable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your js fiddle I rather put `right:0;` and position it absolute http://jsfiddle.net/yjsbdLdk/2/

Comment: Please put the code here - if jsFiddle goes down, this answer becomes useless

Comment: As you can see the social icon have gap between it. How can i remove the gap. Please help me?

Comment: because the image has space itself try to edit the image in photoshop and remove the space.

Comment: my tiny image dont have a space. >> http://i1303.photobucket.com/albums/ag152/empayarmasr/twitter-iconcopy_zpsd8fe44c3.png

Comment: without the space, how can the code make gap by itself?

Comment: Ok I saw it, First move the `div` of the `ul class="social"` inside the div of `reach` and remove all the css of `class social`

Comment: winresh24, could you help me to change my code at http://jsfiddle.net to make it clear. TQ

Comment: yeah sure, just follow the html and css here http://jsfiddle.net/vp2duno8/ everything will go fine, don't mind yet the result on jsfiddle. hope that helps

Comment: I told you to put it inside the `div reach` and remove the css of `social`. follow that

Answer (score 0):

Deleted my original answer. I don't think I should have assumed what your layout was like, nor should Winresh be assuming you can just use absolute positioning.

Just use the clear property. It's much simpler.

http://jsfiddle.net/yjsbdLdk/6/

```
 <div class='reach'>
     // Search form
 </div>
 <div class='clear'></div>
 <ul id='social'>
     // Social list
 </ul>

 .clear{
    clear:right;
 }
```